# Putty known host keys

Tags: ssh, batch, putty

I'm trying to script an ssh connection to host via a batch script using putty. The host key changes in host reboot. then it needs a user click of "yes" when the security alert is displayed.

My batch script `ssh_connection.bat` does :

```
putty.exe -ssh user@my_host -m mycommand.txt
```

I tried to add `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` in `.ssh/config` but it didn't work.

My setup is a computer connected to a host with eth, both has no access to internet. so security do not matter for test I am trying to perform.

So what I am looking for: either keep my host key unchanged, bypass the security alert, or auto press yes whenever the alert is displaye.

Comment: I have already wrote you that you cannot bypass the security alert in PuTTY. If you want to ask about *"keeping host key unchanged"*, I suggest you ask a way more specific question about that. And provide a way more information about the server/host.

Comment: The key shouldn't change on reboot to begin with. Could it be that it's the same key but your "server" in on a DHCP address that actually changes? Using `plink` might be preferable.

Comment: https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.77/htmldoc/AppendixA.html#faq-hostkeys
https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.77/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink
https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments to the question, you're not going to get there with Putty without some kind of higher-level `GUI` testing type tool.

However, as you're using `PuTTY`, that means you're using Windows, so I recommend installing `**Cygwin**` and using it instead. You get as full-on `linux` / `unix` environment as is reasonably possible, including `OpenSSH`, both server and client, and they comport pretty darned well with the standard versions of `OpenSSH`.

`Bash` is the default shell included and several other shells are available as well, though I think `zsh` is no longer supported. And, you get a lot more tools you'll likely find helpful as well.

`Cygwin` is a `RedHat` project, and I've been using it for, oh, more than 20 years! It works great and is a current, on-going project. A simple web search will get you to all you need.

*However I don't recommend installing "everything."* Just do the base install and then add what you need, especially `ssh`. At most, pick whole categories like, say "system tools". Getting everything is WAY more than anyone needs!

Comment: Windows (10 and 11) now has OpenSSH tools built-in. No need to install Cygwin.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I didn't know that, thanks!